# How to Impement Spotify's Authorization Code With PKCE in Kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, authentication, spotify, restful-authentication

So I want to use Spotify's Web API. I have read some documentation that you' ll need to implement an Authentication code with PKCE. I am not 100% sure on how to do that and can use some help with that.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One of the approaches would be to use the *Spotify authorization library*.
Before starting add the following dependency to Your Android project:

```
// Spotify authorization
implementation 'com.spotify.android:auth:1.2.5'
```

And then start coding following the steps from the [*Authorization Guide*](https://developer.spotify.com/documentation/general/guides/authorization-guide/):

**1. Create the code verifier and challenge**

This [helpful article](https://auth0.com/docs/flows/call-your-api-using-the-authorization-code-flow-with-pkce) helps to handle the initial cryptographic part of the authorization flow. You can give it a quick read.

The first step in coding would be to create a `companion object` in which we will store things like the `CLIENT_ID` or the code verifier and code challenge:

```kotlin
companion object {
        const val CLIENT_ID = "your_client_id"
        const val REDIRECT_URI = "https://com.company.app/callback"

        val CODE_VERIFIER = getCodeVerifier()

        private fun getCodeVerifier(): String {
            val secureRandom = SecureRandom()
            val code = ByteArray(64)
            secureRandom.nextBytes(code)
            return Base64.encodeToString(
                code,
                Base64.URL_SAFE or Base64.NO_WRAP or Base64.NO_PADDING
            )
        }

        fun getCodeChallenge(verifier: String): String {
            val bytes = verifier.toByteArray()
            val messageDigest = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA-256")
            messageDigest.update(bytes, 0, bytes.size)
            val digest = messageDigest.digest()
            return Base64.encodeToString(
                digest,
                Base64.URL_SAFE or Base64.NO_WRAP or Base64.NO_PADDING
            )
        }
    }
```

**2. Construct the authorization URI**

This step boils down to using the `AuthorizationRequest.Builder` and `AuthorizationClient` to create an intent for the Spotify Authentication activity.

There You will provide all the necessary parameters from the guide:

```kotlin
fun getLoginActivityCodeIntent(): Intent =
        AuthorizationClient.createLoginActivityIntent(
            activity,
            AuthorizationRequest.Builder(CLIENT_ID, AuthorizationResponse.Type.CODE, REDIRECT_URI)
                .setScopes(
                    arrayOf(
                        "user-library-read", "user-library-modify",
                        "app-remote-control", "user-read-currently-playing"
                    )
                )
                .setCustomParam("code_challenge_method", "S256")
                .setCustomParam("code_challenge", getCodeChallenge(CODE_VERIFIER))
                .build()
        )
```

**3. Your app redirects the user to the authorization URI**

Here you can register a callback for the result of the authorization activity that will use the intent that we have created in the previous step:

```kotlin
private val showLoginActivityCode = registerForActivityResult(
        ActivityResultContracts.StartActivityForResult()
    ) { result: ActivityResult ->

        val authorizationResponse = AuthorizationClient.getResponse(result.resultCode, result.data)

        when (authorizationResponse.type) {
            AuthorizationResponse.Type.CODE ->
                // Here You will get the authorization code which you
                // can get with authorizationResponse.code
            AuthorizationResponse.Type.ERROR ->
                // Handle the Error
            else ->
                // Probably interruption
        }
    }


// Usage:
showLoginActivityCode.launch(getLoginActivityCodeIntent())
```

In there You will have access to the *authorization code* - `authorizationResponse.code`. It will be used in the next step.

**4. Your app exchanges the code for an access token**

Here we are going to have to create another intent for the Spotify Authentication activity. This is very similar to the code from the step 2. Here in the `getLoginActivityTokenIntent` You will have to provide the code that You have retrieved from the previous step:

```kotlin
fun getLoginActivityTokenIntent(code: String): Intent =
        AuthorizationClient.createLoginActivityIntent(
            activity,
            AuthorizationRequest.Builder(CLIENT_ID, AuthorizationResponse.Type.TOKEN, REDIRECT_URI)
                .setCustomParam("grant_type", "authorization_code")
                .setCustomParam("code", code)
                .setCustomParam("code_verifier", CODE_VERIFIER)
                .build()
        )
```

Then create the callback:

```kotlin
private val showLoginActivityToken = registerForActivityResult(
        ActivityResultContracts.StartActivityForResult()
    ) { result: ActivityResult ->

        val authorizationResponse = AuthorizationClient.getResponse(result.resultCode, result.data)

        when (authorizationResponse.type) {
            AuthorizationResponse.Type.TOKEN -> {
                // Here You can get access to the authorization token
                // with authorizationResponse.token
            }
            AuthorizationResponse.Type.ERROR ->
                // Handle Error
            else ->
                // Probably interruption
        }
    }


// Usage:
showLoginActivityToken.launch(getLoginActivityTokenIntent(authorizationCode))
```

Now here the authorization part comes to an end - You have got the access to the authorization token - `authorizationResponse.token`. Save it, it will be used in creating requests to the Spotify Web API.

**5. Use the access token to access the Spotify Web API**

You can start using the API. Simple preview example using Retrofit:

```kotlin
interface SpotifyApi {

    companion object {
        const val BASE_URL = "https://api.spotify.com/v1/"
    }

    @GET("me")
    suspend fun getMe(@Header("Authorization") bearerWithToken: String): User
}
```

Note that the `bearerWithToken` parameter should look like this: `"Bearer {your_access_token}"`.